# How to save a user response in html and then save it on their computer so they can see it next time?

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio, input, windows-store-apps

I am relatively new to coding. I am making a Windows Store App and I need some code (JavaScript) so that when a someone types into a text-box and then clicks on a button, their input gets saved onto their computer (as a '.txt' for example) and next time they load that page of the app, they will be able to see what they typed in.

Here is an example of what I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Example_Of_What_I_Have</title>

<!-- WinJS references -->
<link href="//Microsoft.WinJS.2.0/css/ui-dark.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.2.0/js/base.js"></script>
<script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.2.0/js/ui.js"></script>

<!-- Example_Of_What_I_Have references -->
<link href="/css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="/js/default.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="default.js">
    <input type="text" name="inputBox" /> 
    <input type="submit" name="submitbutton" value="Submit" />
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

I think that the JavaScript code should go in the default.js file. I wouldn't know where though, so here it is:

```
// For an introduction to the Blank template, see the following documentation:
// http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=232509
(function () {
"use strict";

var app = WinJS.Application;
var activation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;

app.onactivated = function (args) {
    if (args.detail.kind === activation.ActivationKind.launch) {
        if (args.detail.previousExecutionState !==      
activation.ApplicationExecutionState.terminated) {
            // TODO: This application has been newly launched. Initialize
            // your application here.
        } else {
            // TODO: This application has been reactivated from suspension.
            // Restore application state here.
        }
        args.setPromise(WinJS.UI.processAll());
    }
};

app.oncheckpoint = function (args) {
    // TODO: This application is about to be suspended. Save any state
    // that needs to persist across suspensions here. You might use the
    // WinJS.Application.sessionState object, which is automatically
    // saved and restored across suspension. If you need to complete an
    // asynchronous operation before your application is suspended, call
    // args.setPromise().
};

app.start();
```

})();

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try [HTML5 Web Storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).

Example:

```
// Store
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=localStorage.getItem("lastname");
```